# Ruby rails - jquery auto complete - combine multiple values for a list item

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I parse values of an rails instance variable to create an auto complete list of jQuery? 
So my '/user/search' return an instance variable with multiple values per item. I wanna combine them and present as a list item.

```
def search
  if (params[:term] =~ /[a-zA-Z]/)
    @result = User.FindLdap("sAMAccountName", params[:term])
  else
    @result = User.FindLdap("idnumber", params[:term])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :partial => 'text_for_autocomplete'}
    format.js
  end
end
```

I am using jQuery's example code, but it has a way to display each item list as it is. In my case I retrieve multiple ldap attributes and I want to show those attributes values for each list item. 
So each list item shall be like `""#{sAMAccountName}", "#{idnumber}""` seperated by a comma, instead of just value of idnumber that was typed in the text field.

```
$(function() {
    $("#term").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.post("/users/search", request, response);
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        } #No idea how it can be done here. 
    });
});
```

I get this in the list, html of the partial render -

[image: I get this in the list, actual partial render]

Comment: why don't you use JSON instead of HTML response, use JBuilder gem to render response as you wish. Your problem here is that you are getting HTML from server and its escaped.

Comment: @MilanJaric - Thanks. Not sure how to do that, never did it before. I will try.

Comment: its same as you would create erb html view, here is link for head start http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

Comment: @MilanJaric - But can jQuery read that to list? Wouldn't that have same issue? Instead of html it will be jason.

Comment: drop in question sample JSON data and I can write you sample code in JavaScript

Comment: @MilanJaric - Just posted a new question specifically for jason and jquery autocomplete list. It is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393401/ruby-rails-parse-json-to-jquery-ajax-autocomplete-list

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to look at [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). JBuilder is strong, well-defined and reliable solution for json-output.