# Ruby - multidimensional hash

Tags: ruby

How do I make this multidimensional? Each search result entry has multiple attributes `:attributes => ['sAMAccountName','givenName','SN','mail']`. and there can be many entries in the result. This code is good for creating only one entry with multiple attributes.

```
  def self.Find(attribute, loginID)
        conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                             :port => PORT,
                             :base => BASE,
                             :auth => { 
                                         :username => 'admin',
                                         :password => 'admin',
                                         :method => :simple
                                      }
        if  conn.bind
          result = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
          conn.search( :base => LDAPBASE,
                       :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( attribute, loginID+"*" ),
                       :attributes => ['sAMAccountName','givenName','SN','mail'],
                       :return_result => true
                      ).each do |entries|
                        entries.each do |attribute, values|
                          values.each do |value|
                            result[attribute] = value
                          end
                        end
                      end
          result
        end
  end
```

The actual response I get from ldap is like this -

`puts result.to_s`

```
{
 "dn"=>"CN=somename\\, somefirstname,OU=Users,DC=site,DC=com", 
 "sn"=>"somename", 
 "givenname"=>"somefirstname",
 "samaccountname"=>"someuserid", 
 "mail"=>"someone@somthing.com"
}
```

Since the search is has * wildcard to find all matching entries. Ldap will return multiple entries in the format above.  similar to this -

```
    {
      "dn"=>"CN=somename\\, somefirstname1,OU=Users,DC=site,DC=com", 
      "sn"=>"somename1", 
      "givenname"=>"somefirstname1",
      "samaccountname"=>"someuserid1", 
      "mail"=>"someone1@somthing.com"
    },
    {
      "dn"=>"CN=somename\\, somefirstname2,OU=Users,DC=site,DC=com", 
      "sn"=>"somename2", 
      "givenname"=>"somefirstname2", 
      "samaccountname"=>"someuserid2",
      "mail"=>"someone2@somthing.com"
    },
    {
      "dn"=>"CN=somename\\, somefirstname3,OU=Users,DC=site,DC=com",
      "sn"=>"somename3",
      "givenname"=>"somefirstname3",
      "samaccountname"=>"someuserid3", 
      "mail"=>"someone3@somthing.com"
    },


A[a=>1,b=>11,c=>111]
B[a=>2,b=>22,c=>222]
C[a=>3,b=>33,c=>333]
D[a=>4,b=>44,c=>444]
```

Comment: You must attach result of the conn.search call and example in form that you want to obtain.

Comment: The example above is what you want?

Comment: @PaulChechetin - Hey Paul, I updated my question.

Comment: Cool, I figure out the question!

Comment: @PaulChechetin - See my update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood the question.

```
def self.Find(attribute, loginID)
        conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                             :port => PORT,
                             :base => BASE,
                             :auth => { 
                                         :username => 'admin',
                                         :password => 'admin',
                                         :method => :simple
                                      }
        if  conn.bind
          conn.search( :base => LDAPBASE,
                       :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( attribute, loginID+"*" ),
                       :attributes => ['sAMAccountName','givenName','SN','mail'],
                       :return_result => true
                      ).reduce(Array.new) do |acc, el|

                         #
                         # Any modification of the entry must be here
                         #

                         acc + [el] 

                      end
          end
        end
end
```

I think `Array.map` is good choice too

My assumption:

- conn.search return Array of Hash
- the form of result you want:

  ```
  [
        {"uid":"123","displayName":"User 123","mail":"123@example.com"},
        {"uid":"456","displayName":"User 456","mail":"456@example.com"},
        {"uid":"789","displayName":"User 789","mail":"789@example.com"}
  ]
  ```

Comment: I just modified the expect result of your post. Basically I want an hash reference array that contains arrays with attributes and their values.

Comment: I think you want array of hash that contains attributes and their values. Is it right?

Comment: I think I need some explanation yet. Because what you need is what you have ( result of `conn.search` call is array that contains arrays with attributes and their values already) And what else do you want?

Comment: This question is actually tied to my different question on json. I am still thinking how exactly I need to format the output for jason and jQuery. Here is the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392734/ruby-rails-jquery-auto-complete-combine-multiple-values-for-a-list-item#comment13402243_10392734